# CSS - Responsive side-by-side images

Tags: html, css, image

I know I'm missing something simple here - just need a second pair of eyes. I'm working on a header that consists of two  columns:

Column 1: A single image, 200x150
Column 2: An image carousel ("slick" library) that consists of 640x150 images

So the total max width here is 840 pixels.

When the browser size shrinks below 840 pixels, I want the contents of both columns to shrink equally. So at 420 pixels wide, I'd expect Column 1's image to be 100x75, and Column 2's images to be 320x75.

I'm using the W3.CSS stylesheet, and I've got the w3-content and w3-row s set up, but I can't seem to find the right combination of styling for the inside contents. The general idea here is (I've stripped it down to the basics):

```
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:840px;">
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div id="logo" style="float:left;width:25%;position:relative;display:block;">
      <span style="position:absolute;top:0%;left:0%;max-width:200px;">
        <img src="logo/logo.png" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">
      </span>
      <span style="position:absolute;top:0%;left:0%;max-width:175px;">
        <img src="logo/logo2.png" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">
      </span>
    </div>
    <div id="carousel" style="float:right;width:75%;max-width:640px;">
      <div><img src="1.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></div>
      <div><img src="2.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></div>
      <div><img src="3.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9ajv244j/2/

Now, I've taken this a little further by overlaying multiple images on top of each other within the logo  (part of the requirements and the images cannot be combined). So far, this is working fine in Chrome, but the images within the logo  don't scale in Internet Explorer (IE 11 is the version being tested).

Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm missing here?

UPDATE: It seems as though the "position:absolute" style on the image's  is what is causing IE not to resize the image properly. Still not sure how to fix it, though.

Comment: i looked again and again about your question, but i still don't get it. can you input some image for us, about what you tried to achieve?

Comment: @Obink - I've edited the question and added a Fiddle with example images.

Answer (score 0):

@jhilgeman Try following media query in your css:

```css
@media(max-width: 420px) {
    #logo{
        width:100px !important;
        height:75px !important;
    }
  
  #carousel{
        width:320px !important;
        height:75px !important;
      }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to scale the images smoothly by percentage, not by fixed sizes. I only provided the 420px resolution as an example of what the image sizes should be when scaled down to that size.

Comment: @jhilgeman In that case you may consider to use Bootstrap, which will be very easy to handle at any level.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to redo the way I was overlapping the images by eliminating the spans altogether and just positioning the images directly:

```
<div class="logopics">
  <img src="1.jpg" class="autosize" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:10px; z-index:0">
  <img src="2.png" class="autosize" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:20px; z-index:1">
</div>
```

Fixed version:
https://jsfiddle.net/9ajv244j/7/